# how to find a label in the itemtemplate on gridview?C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView that bound some data from DB and have a label in the ItemTemplate and EditTextbox in the EditItemTemplate they are in the same TemplateField. In the GridView some user has no data in somewhere field, If I want to insert a data for these user, I need to find GirdView label first and var the edittextbox, when updating I can Compare the value of them , such as the edittextbox value not equals to labeldata value then insert,
but I can't find the value of the label when rowupdating or databound of gridview

how can i do it ?

I have try

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (rowCount >= 1)
            {
                Label lbDA_TEL_HK_NO = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblKM_TEL"));
                Session["DA_TEL_HK_NO"] = lbDA_TEL_HK_NO.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

It can find all the gridview data but not which I selected

P.S I'm a newbie, please help me

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "香港內線">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblHK_TEL" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("[DA_TEL_HK_NO]")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHK_TEL" runat="server" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')"  MaxLength="3"
        Text='<%# Eval("[DA_TEL_HK_NO]")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: can you show your aspx markup

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this for read all rows in grid view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var label = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblKM_TEL") as Label;

    if (label != null)
    {
        // Manipulate label control
    }
}
```

Or you can gets label from selected row:

```
var label = GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblKM_TEL") as Label;

if (label != null)
{
    // Manipulate label control
}
```

Comment: I will try this but i want to know where should I put these code into?

Comment: The title of your question it's about read controls from grid view's rows, if I understand our comment, your real question is "How to get modified values from grid view edit item template", That's right ?

Comment: yes I want to get the value from item template but not edit item template,

Comment: I can get value from edit item template but i can't get the label value when show data,  because I have to know if the data of field is null , when I click edit I can insert the new data of the user

Answer (score 1):

From your aspx markup you are using the wrong label id .

you need yo use this label id `lblHK_TEL`

You code looks as follows after changes

```
Label lbDA_TEL_HK_NO = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblHK_TEL"));
```

Comment: I just copy once of my label for example